# "Embed" a global variable in javascript file using grunt

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

I have a .js file in my project with code like that:

```
var API_ENDPOINT = 'http://example.com:8000';
var api = new RemoteApi(API_ENDPOINT);
```

where `API_ENDPOINT` changes among dev/prod environments

It's not a js application, mostly a classic server-side app (Django) with some client-side enhacements.

I started using Grunt for managing client-side dependencies and thought, it'd be a good idea to specify `API_ENDPOINT` in Grunt config and somehow "embed" it into .js file.

But I can't find a way to mangle files with Grunt.

The resulting .js file will be run in browser envorenment, so I need my `API_ENDPOINT` variable embedded in source.js file or creating a separate .js file like

```
var API_ENDPOINT = '...';
```

which I will include before script.js

(Also, I'd like to "embed" this variable into my django's `settings.py`)

Comment: You want to search replace the variables with different values as per environment?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

for the clientside js i would extract all configs into a `config.json` file, and use [grunt-replace](https://github.com/outaTiME/grunt-replace) for injection to your code.

the folder structure could look like this:

```
- Gruntfile
- config.json
- client/
  - src/
    - script.js
  - dist/
```

**config.json**

```
{
  "API_ENDPOINT": "http://example.com:8000"
}
```

**src/script.js**

```
var API_ENDPOINT = '@@API_ENDPOINT'; // everything starting with @@ will be replaced by grunt-replace by default
var api = new RemoteApi(API_ENDPOINT);
```

**Gruntfile**

```
grunt.initConfig({
  replace: {
    dist: {
      options: {
        patterns: [{
         json: require('config.json')
        }]
      },
      files: [
        {expand: true, flatten: true, src: ['./client/src/*.js'], dest: './client/dist/'}
      ]
    }
  }
});
```

some details:

- your final clientsidecode will reside in `client/dist`
- requiring a json-file will automatically parse it
- of course you can do it with yaml/cson (see [grunt-replace section](https://github.com/outaTiME/grunt-replace#patternsyaml))
- dont know on how to parse a json-config in python, but it shouldn't be to difficult...